# Wrong Root Name Appearing in Terminal | MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal, malware, root

I just noticed today that a weird name that appeared on my teminal "rrmando2x13g" as shown in the image below. Usually only my computer name (removed in cyan) used to appear.

Does this mean its a malware or someone else has logged in to my computer?

[image]

Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: Can you verify what are Local Hostname, Hostname and Computer name on your Mac with terminal command : `scutil --get LocalHostName`  then `scutil --get HostName`   and `scutil --get ComputerName`

Comment: @Jean_JD both the commands `--get LocalHostName` and `--get ComputerName` gives me proper names, `scutil --get HostName` however results in `HostName: not set`

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The name on the left is the name of your user directory.

You can change the name in the system settings under Accounts & Users

On the right the name is the HostName.

You can change your host name persistently
`sudo scutil —set HostName YourHostname`

Comment: Changing the directory name in Accounts & Users is **dangerous** and can, e.g. if there is only one account on the system, block you from accessing the system. If you recommend this, please also describe the detailed steps required to avoid problems.

Comment: I really dont have any user directory under the name rrmando2x13g. It just appeared today!

Comment: I'm not going to say anything wrong, I mean, I'll redirect you directly to the Apple site: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548 Please tell me if it was your problem.  If you suspect malware, I recommend installing Malwarebytes or Combo Cleaner and scanning the system.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So you can give a name to your HostName :

```
sudo scutil --set Hostname "The name you want"
```

You will have to give your password for this operation. And it's nor appear when you give it.